# Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of async function without a catch block although i didn't use try, await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord, discord.js

I'm very new on Node.JS and i code on my Discord.JS and do hosting on heroku.com

When i run it on my terminal, it runs as well
But when i run it with the heroku, it return error

Here's the log

[image]

It keeps saying

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag '--unhandled-rejections=strict' (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2)

and

> [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
> deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
> will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

That error still exist even though i didn't use any of `Promise.any`

in my code, i used `collector` and `collected`, for the async function, but when i insert the `.catch()` at the end of those async function, it shows warning `(,) expected`. When i insert the `,` in front of `catch()` it shows warning `(Arguments expression expected)`.

Here's preview of my code :

```js
collector.on('end', collected => {
                        //Respond Collector
                        let newContentInput = '';
                        collected.forEach((message) => {
                            newContentInput += message.content.split(" ");
                        });
                        
                        //Proccess Failed
                        if (collected.size === 0) {
                            message.reply(`Proses gagal :frowning::thumbsdown:`);
                            return;
                        } //Proccess Canceled
                        let x = 0;
                        if (cancel(newContentInput,x) === 1) return;
                                                
                        //DupBadWord Check
                        let newContent = newContentInput.split(`,`);
                        knwContent = [];
                        unkContent = [];
                        count = newContent.length;
                        let fProc = Boolean;
                        fProc = false;
                        let sProc = Boolean;
                        sProc = false;

                        //Check new input = Known/Unknown
                        function knownBadWord (i) {
                            knownCheck = badWordsDB
                            .includes(newContent[i].toLowerCase());                            
                            return knownCheck;
                        };

                        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            if (knownBadWord(i)) {  
                                knwContent.push(newContent[i]); //Identified as known word
                                fProc = true;
                            } else {             
                                unkContent.push(newContent[i]); //Identified as unknown word
                                sProc = true;
                            }
                        }

                        fText = `sudah ada di dalam ${haram} :sob::thumbsdown:`;
                        sText = `akan ditambahkan ke ${haram} :weary::ok_hand:`;
                        sConf = `Apakah anda yakin? \`YES\` || \`NO\``;
                        if (fProc === false) {
                            message.channel.send(`Siap! Kata \`${unkContent}\` ${sText}\n${sConf}`);
                            confirmation(unkContent,count,code);
                        } 
                        else if (fProc === true && sProc === true) {
                            message.channel.send(`Kata \`${unkContent}\` ${sText}` + 
                            `\nNamun kata \`${knwContent}\` ${fText}\n${sConf}`);
                            confirmation(unkContent,count,code);
                        } 
                        else if (fProc === true) {
                            message.channel.send(`Maaf! Kata \`${knwContent}\` ${fText}`);
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Your error log image does not show in full. If you have Heroku CLI installed, run `heroku logs -a yourAppName -n=100`, where `n` is the number of lines to output. And then it should show you the exact line where your error originates from. Right now it starts somewhere in the middle `at RequestHandler.execute()....` but that's not really helpful to determine what is causing this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).